# UI Angular Bootstrap modal template inserted inside modal-content

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I use UI Angular Bootstrap modal dialog and I open it this way:

```
$modal.open({
                templateUrl: 'angular/loanscenario/modal.html',
                backdrop: 'static',
                dialogFade: false,
                keyboard: false
            });
```

And I have tamplate looking like this:

```
<div class="modal custom-modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>My template.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Why is this template completely inserted inside Bootstrap modal-content tags. How can you change that behavior? I want to write those tags myself and some custom css classes to them.

Comment: Which version of bootstrap are you implementing?

Comment: @bambi - this is not the twitter bootstrap modal dialog. You are using the UI Bootstrap written in angular.

Comment: @potatopeelings You must be right, I made mistake. Lol :D

Comment: The template is inserted in to the page because that is how Angular directives work. On the bright side, you can still edit the default templates and style them to suit your requirements.